# Как правильно запустить и остановить поток?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5, qml

Приложение, в котором интерфейс реализован с помощью qml в среде QtCreator.
Для передачи параметров воспользовался следующим способом, объявленным в главном методе Main:

```
QQuickView viewer;
deviceScaner=new scaner;
viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("deviceScaner",deviceScaner);
```

Далее из Qml вызываю напрямую методы `deviceScaner(**Type** paramethr)`.
Класс сканер реализован в отдельных файлах (интерфейс и реализация).

Задача следующая: есть устройство, которое с большой частотой шлет данные для визуализации. Пробовал по-разному передать метод в поток, класс в поток (через `MoveToThread`), результат - либо ошибка при сборке, либо зависание. Необходимо отрисовывать данные как можно быстрее (за это отвечает один метод который достает из области памяти эти данные) так, чтобы весь остальной интерфейс был рабочий и отзывчивый.

Не могу понять где создавать объект потока, а так же где и как правильно передавать параметры в него, с учетом того что интерфейс на qtquick.

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю следующим образом. Отдельный класс как посредник между интерфейсом и классами функционала. Отдельный класс для создания потока-обертки взят [из Хабрахабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/203254/). По ссылке довольно подробно расписано.

В Main.cpp я использую другой метод:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QObject *root = engine.rootObjects()[0];
Foo *foo= new Foo(root); //класс-посредник
```

Соответственно в классе Foo интерфейс привязывается следующим образом:

```
Foo::Foo(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

    root = parent; //указатель на интерфейс

}
```

В заголовочном файле не забудьте создать `QObject *root;`

Данные между qml-интерфейсом и классами на С++ можно передавать разными способами. Я использую сигналы и слоты. В qml создаётся сигнал, например `signal qmlLoad(string file)`, когда надо, вы его вызываете. В классе посреднике вы его соединяете следующим образом:

```
connect(root, SIGNAL(qmlLoad(QString)), this, SLOT(someLoad(QString)));
```

Для связи с потоком тоже ничего сложного. Вот передача строки от потока в интерфейс(прописывается в том же классе, где создаются потоки. В моём случае это класс-посредник):

```
connect(*_obj, SIGNAL(iniReady(QString)), root, SIGNAL(iniReady(QString)));
```

А в его обработка вызывается очень просто:

```
signal iniReady(string name)

onIniReady: {
        for (var i = 0; i < loaderModel.count; i++) {
            if (loaderModel.get(i).name === name) {
                loaderModel.setProperty("number", i)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```